# teamcity run several build projects with on revision

Tags: build, teamcity, revision

I would like to run several Team-City build projects with the same SVN-revision. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at snapshot dependencies. If build configuration A has a snapshot dependency on B then when A is triggered B will be triggered too and both will run on the same sources.

If A and B have same VCS roots then builds of these configurations will be built on the same revision. If A and B have different VCS roots, then TeamCity will take sources on the same moment of time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create several build configurations, and set them to trigger on SVN revision changes to a shared repository root.

You can also have one build trigger another.

Comment: When one build triggers another, do both use the same revision?

Comment: Thats really up to you...if you want them to then yes they can

Comment: This can cause a build storm if people frequently check-in. Better to build when needed.

Answer (score 0):

SnapShot builds allow this, and reuse builds. So, if you have 5 steps, and steps 1-4 were run last week, running step 5 won't require running 1-4 again. Conversely, running step 5 would run 1-5 if none of them had been run before, and all will use the same checkout revision numbers.

For a simple case of 3 steps, just:

1. Set Build 3 to have a snapshot dependency on Build 2.
2. Set Build 2 to have a snapshot dependency on Build 1.

Now you'll have Build 1 -> Build 2 -> Build 3.

This does given you neat charts:
[image]